# javascripts not loading in EDGE and Chrome but work in IE

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, mainframe, cics

Web frontend that is all stored on the mainframe and runs in CICS TS.  Works fine in IE but not EDGE.

In Edge get the following error:
Refused to execute script from 'http://999.999.99.999:3028/objserv/RMFGEN01.js' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable.

I replaced the actual IP with nines just to hide the IP address in this question.  It has the correct location on the mainframe where the script is stored and again it works in IE.  Any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks!
David

Comment: Why is your script being served as a GIF? IE, in classic IE fashion, doesn't care, but modern browsers do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I assume based on your URL that you have a URIMAP defined in CICS.  If this URIMAP is defined to serve static files then you probably need to check that its also got the mediatype specified correctly for the .js file.

Answer (score 1):

David -- take a look at the URIMAP that is controlling the URL for your JavaScript file(s).

If your path in the URIMAP is /objserv/* then you would have set one MIME type in the URIMAP definition.  This can be a problem when you have different file types in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  We determined there wasn't a URIMAP being used to we try to implement one but still having issues.  We figured out that OBJSERV is actually a CICS program that was setting the media type parm.  We update that program to pass text/javascript for .js requests and we are up and running on Edge and Chrome.  Thanks!

Comment: @dbowers73 From your comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You can post the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. We determined there wasn't a URIMAP being used and we tried to implement one but still having issues. We figured out that OBJSERV is actually a CICS program that was setting the media type parm. We updated that program to pass text/javascript for .js requests and we are up and running on Edge and Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: This should be a comment to the previous answer